# How to get a value of QTimeEdit,QCheckBox and QDateTimeEdit into a variable. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4

I'm starting with PyQt4 and I'm making a program for practice. In that program I have `QDateTimeEdit`, `QTimeEdit` and `QCheckBox`.

How would I pull values from them into a string using signals and slots.

Comment: Show us what you trying, do you have any code which you trying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys


class main_frame(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        # A push buttnon
        btn_get = QPushButton("Get Time", self)
        btn_get.move(100, 250)

        #       
        time = QTime()
        # Find what is the local/system time
        curent_t = time.currentTime()
        # Convert it to a str
        # The output shoud be HH:MM:SS  , eg 10:45:28
        curent_t_str = curent_t.toString()


        # Create a timeEdit widget 
        time_widget = QTimeEdit(time, self)
        time_widget.setTime(curent_t)

        def get_time():
            print(curent_t_str)

        btn_get.clicked.connect(get_time)


        ### At the end of the day you got curent_t_str variable
        ### which you can use it in your code down the road
        ### so I belive that`s helpful for your needs
        ### implement this may vary, depending your needs ...

        # Set a costom size for the mainWindow
        self.setFixedSize(300, 300)

def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = main_frame()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Does that help you out ? Note that for **QDateTimeEdit** the procedure is the same, after you got your value into format like 10:45:28 is up to you how you gonna format the string or for what you gonna use